# CSS Display Changes on different machines. What is wrong with the CSS below?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have a web application that displays differently on multiple machines.  I've dealt with similar issues with browsers and I'm familiar with screen resolutions but my app displays differently on multiple computers that are all the same type of make and model.  The app is only supported on IE and we're all running the same version of explorer (IE 11).  The CSS and body are provided below.  I'm also attaching a couple pictures that show what the page should look like.  I've done a lot of reading and the only thing I can think of is that it might have something to do with the font-size properties that have been set.  I should note that the buttons above the video (see pictures) are defined with HTML character codes.

[image: Good display]

[image: Poor display]

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  margin: 0px;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  height: 655px;
  border: solid 5px RGB(75, 75, 75);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

#headerDiv {
  background-color: RGB(75, 75, 75);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 5px;
}

#egisID {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 82px;
  color: RGB(255, 255, 255);
}

#refreshL {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 82px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#refreshL2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 82px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#refreshL:active {
  z-index: 1;
}

#headText {
  position: absolute;
  left: 455px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 400%;
  top: -30px;
  color: RGB(255, 255, 255);
}

#embed1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 320px;
}

#cDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#label1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: RGB(75, 75, 75);
  color: RGB(255, 255, 255);
  border: 2px solid RGB(250, 0, 0);
  font-size: 160%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

#label1:hover {
  background-color: RGB(75, 75, 75);
  border: 2px solid RGB(220, 190, 0);
}

#label1:active {
  background-color: RGB(150, 150, 150);
  border: 2px solid RGB(250, 0, 0);
}

#label11 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100px;
}

#playAll {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: RGB(75, 75, 75);
  color: RGB(255, 255, 255);
  border: 2px solid RGB(250, 0, 0);
  font-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#playAll:hover {
  background-color: RGB(75, 75, 75);
  border: 2px solid RGB(220, 190, 0);
}

#playAll:active {
  background-color: RGB(150, 150, 150);
  border: 2px solid RGB(250, 0, 0);
}

#pauseAll {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: RGB(75, 75, 75);
  color: RGB(255, 255, 255);
  border: 2px solid RGB(250, 0, 0);
  font-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#pauseAll:hover {
  background-color: RGB(75, 75, 75);
  border: 2px solid RGB(220, 190, 0);
}

#pauseAll:active {
  background-color: RGB(150, 150, 150);
  border: 2px solid RGB(250, 0, 0);
}

#stopAll {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: RGB(75, 75, 75);
  color: RGB(255, 255, 255);
  border: 2px solid RGB(250, 0, 0);
  font-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 150px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#stopAll:hover {
  background-color: RGB(75, 75, 75);
  border: 2px solid RGB(220, 190, 0);
}

#stopAll:active {
  background-color: RGB(150, 150, 150);
  border: 2px solid RGB(250, 0, 0);
}

@media (max-width: 1860px) {
  #map {
    right: 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1580px) {
  #map {
    max-width: 40%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
  #map {
    right: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="headerDiv">
  <img id="logo" src="logoAll.png" height=80 width=300></img>
  <h1 id="headText">The Title</h1>
  <a id="egisID" href="">EGIS</a>
  <img id="refreshL" src="images\refresh.png" onmouseup="refreshFun();"></img>
  <img id="refreshL2" src="images\refresh2.png" onmouseup="refreshFun();"></img>
</div>
<div id="cDiv">
  <label id="label1" for="label11">&#10010;</label>
  <input type="file" id="label11" multiple="true" onchange="setFiles(this);" />
  <input type="button" id="playAll" value="&#9658;" onclick="playFun2();" />
  <input type="button" id="pauseAll" value="&#10074;&#10074;" onclick="pauseFun();" />
  <input type="button" id="stopAll" value="&#9724;" onclick="stopFun();" />

</div>

<div id="map"> </div>

<div class="e11" style="width:660px;position:absolute;left:40px;height:660px;top:150px;border:5px solid RGB(75,75,75);overflow:hidden;">

</div>
```

Comment: from your code, my IE11 shows the 2 divs overlapping on smaller resolution. header seems to need vertical-align or line-height to be reset or tuned. for text/image aligment. too much absolute positionning might be in the way ...

Comment: Try to reorganize the hierarchy of your elements. You have img, h1,a as siblings. Break them down in different containers.